# Using "so that" to indicate consequence

Tags: phrase-usage, conjunctions

Can "so that" be used to indicate consequence? According to searches on the web, "so that" can only be used to indicate purpose or intent (with "in order that" being a synonym), while "so" is used to indicate consequence.

However, contrary to this, I have found many uses of "so that" to indicate consequence.

Examples:

> Their eyes were holden, so that they did not fully recognize divinity in humanity. ([source](https://m.egwwritings.org/en/book/130.2469))

> Intemperance has beclouded the faculties of many, so that Satan has almost complete control of them". ([source](https://whiteestate.org/devotional/fh/10_29/))

> The first difficulty I have with this argument is that severability was not pleaded, nor explored in the trial (never mind fully explored), so that it is too late to try to raise it now. ([source](http://www.saflii.org/za/cases/ZASCA/2000/28.html))

Can "so" be used instead of "so that" in these examples without any problem? If yes, then why was "so that" used in these examples? If we replaced "so that" in these examples with "in order that", wouldn't the sentence sound unnatural?

Comment: Where did you find the example sentences?

Comment: Those examples all sound like older usage, not modern.

Comment: Eddie Kal: https://m.egwwritings.org/en/book/130.2469, https://whiteestate.org/devotional/fh/10_29/ and http://www.saflii.org/za/cases/ZASCA/2000/28.html

StephenS: I would appreciate it if you could answer the questions I wrote above.

Comment: I have edited the source links in. Next time please remember to include a source for your sentences.

Comment: Eddie Kal, do you have anything to say about my questions?